# share content in facebook without "shared a link"

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

i was thinking there is no way to share a link without shared a link mark but i have just seen one facebook page where they have shared the content and there is no mentioning of shared a link remarks.

here is the fb page

```
  https://www.facebook.com/Rajnikant.Vs.CIDJokez?fref=photo
```

i am talking about 4th share this one

```
      http://www.rajnikantvscidjokes.in/30-pictures-taken-just-right-moment-awesome/
```

you can see that there is  no  word about shared a link so people will click this one. but  whenever i share from my fb page it shows shared a link

```
      https://www.facebook.com/pages/Jokes-collection/320302214838280
```

i want to share content link above rajnikanvscidjokes where there is no mnetioning of link so people will think its photo and they will click and eventually reacch to my site.

please help

Comment: What makes you think people would click on a link depending on whether or not it says “shared a link”? Anyway, if you want to post on a page _as_ the page, then you need to use a page access token.

Comment: @CBroe as i said i have already created a page. page access token is something extra?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens